# Python: unreliable results from socket.gethostbyaddr()

Tags: python, ip, dig

I use socket.gethostbyaddr to get the ip of a domain, and it does not give me any results , while ping and dig can return the IP correctly.

```
 >>> import socket
    >>> socket.gethostbyaddr('supplychristianlouboutin.com')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host
```

So it's weird to me why this API is not reliable?Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `socket.gethostbyname('supplychristianlouboutin.com')`

Comment: Great, thanks man! I was really confused why it does return results and for others it does not. Looks like I was doing reverse DNS.